# Use a variables inside Route's element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is there a way to use a variables inside Route's element? The code below run smoothly if I use `<Home/>` for the Route's element, but failed when I set and use a `const`, which is `HomePage` as shown below:

```
   render() {
        const HomePage = () => {
          return (
            <Home />
          );
        };
    
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Header />
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/home" element={HomePage} />
              <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
            </Routes>
            <Footer />
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
    }
```

I am using react-router-dom v6.3.0

Comment: The `element` prop takes a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You are giving element a function and not a component. Either call the function when setting it in the Route, or set the object directly in the variable.

First scenario:

```
render() {
        const HomePage = () => {
          return (
            <Home />
          );
        };
    
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Header />
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/home" element={HomePage()} />
              <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
            </Routes>
            <Footer />
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
    }
```

Second scenario:

```
render() {
            const HomePage = (<Home />);
        
            return (
              <React.Fragment>
                <Header />
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/home" element={HomePage} />
                  <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
                </Routes>
                <Footer />
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          }
        }
```